# Is there any way/tool to visualize Hybris Data Model?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

Is there any way/tool to visualize Hybris Data Model except looking at Hybris type definition xml file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use visual paradigm for this.

[Here is the link for instruction](https://circle.visual-paradigm.com/docs/code-engineering/instant-reverse/how-to-generate-uml-from-xml/)

It needs some work in the configuration, so which extensions should be inspected and which classes are mandantory and which are optional. But if you make this work, afterwards you will get a nice class diagram.

There was/ were also some tools. For example [this one here](https://hybrismart.com/2016/06/20/visual-representation-of-hybris-data-model-items-xml/) but I dont know if there are up to date...

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think EPAM/HybrisMart did not release their tool.

There is also a Hybris UML Tool in the Hybris 5 wiki, but I have not gotten this to work: https://cxwiki.sap.com/display/release5/hybris+UML+Tool

Comment: Thanks, both. Visual Paradigm helped me somewhat